# First angular app in phonegap/cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, phonegap

For a project for school we wrote an angular 2 app with a nodejs backend. Now we need to make an android app. Since we wrote an angular app i know it's possible to cordova/phonegap it. But i can't seem to find a decent how to or tutorial. Can someone link some pages?

a desperate student.

Comment: Take a look at ionicframework https://ionicframework.com/

Comment: yeah i found how-to's with ionic, but can't it be done without it?

Comment: Try this: [https://scotch.io/@vijayk036/building-hybrid-mobile-apps-using-cordova-and-angularjs-for-android](https://scotch.io/@vijayk036/building-hybrid-mobile-apps-using-cordova-and-angularjs-for-android)

Comment: @Frix33 He's not asking to do it with angularJS

Comment: "Since we wrote an angular app i know it's possible to cordova/phonegap it. But i can't seem to find a decent how to or tutorial."

Comment: @Frix33 note the difference between angular and angularjs. angularjs is angular 1, just "angular" is all the other versions because angular 2 is almost completely different than angularjs

Comment: Oh ok sorry..Maybe this one? [https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2](https://www.becompany.ch/en/blog/2016/10/19/creating-apache-cordova-app-with-angular2)